# How to pass context to the django static template tag

Tags: python, django

I have an image with the name `image1.png`.
Image name is stored in the `context_image` like `context_image = 'image1.png'`. How to pass my `context_image` to this code
`{% static "images/image1.png" %}`?
I try this `{% static "images/{{ context_image }}" %}` but this code ain't working.

Comment: You've got {{}} inside {%%}
Try the add filter
{% static "images/"|add:context_image %}

Comment: or `src='{% static "images" %}/{{ context_image }}'`

Comment: none of this ain't works